# Pandas conditional creation while exluding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe

```
col1 col2 col3
a    b    c
d    e    f
g    h    i
```

I write the following

```
df['col1'] = np.where((df['col2'].str.contains('b',case = False,regex=True,na=False)) & 
                      (df['col3'].str.contains('c',case = False,regex=True,na=False)),'s', 'o')
```

I now get this

```
col1 col2 col3
s    b    c
o    e    f
o    h    i
```

I now want to do the following where col1 NOT equal to s

```
df['col1'] = np.where((df['col1'] != 's') &
                      (df['col2'].str.contains('e',case = False,regex=True,na=False)) & 
                      (df['col3'].str.contains('f',case = False,regex=True,na=False)),'z','x')
```

I want the following

```
col1 col2 col3
s    b    c
z    e    f
x    h    i
```

But I get this instead

```
col1 col2 col3
x    b    c
z    e    f
x    h    i
```

I want the logic to not change s in col1

Comment: It is doing what is expected. `df['col1'] != 's'` is `False` for first row and hence `s` is replaced by `x`. Do you want a different logic to get the output?

Comment: I think i made the edit after the comment can you please look at my output vs desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other efficient solution, may be you can try using following where if `col1` is equal to `s` then return `s` else apply `np.where` with other condition:

```
df['col1'] = np.where((df['col1'] == 's'), 's', 
                      np.where((df['col2'].str.contains('e',case = False,regex=True,na=False)) & 
                               (df['col3'].str.contains('f',case = False,regex=True,na=False)),
                                'z','x')
                     ) 
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    s    b    c
1    z    e    f
2    x    h    i
```

## Update:

For more condition still with `where`:

```
df['col1'] = np.where((df['col1'] == 's'), 's', 
                      np.where((df['col1'] == 'z'), 'z',
                      np.where((df['col2'].str.contains('e',case = False,regex=True,na=False)) & 
                               (df['col3'].str.contains('f',case = False,regex=True,na=False)),
                                'z','x')
                               )
                     ) 
print(df)
```

## Using apply:

First we can create function and then apply to `dataframe`:

```
def function(row):
    if row['col1'] == 's':
        return 's'
    elif row['col1'] == 'z':
        return 'z'
    elif ('e' in row['col2'].lower()) and 'f' in row['col3'].lower():
        return 'z'
    else:
        return 'x'
```

Now, apply function to dataframe:

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    s    b    c
1    z    e    f
2    x    h    i
```

Comment: yes this works! I can see why my way doesn't work because the result is  `False` hence it changes it so x. Thank you!!!! @0p3n5ourcE

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.

Comment: how would I go about keeping two conditions?
`df['col1'] == 's' & df['col1'] =='z'` keep both s and z while changing everything else
@0p3n5ourcE

Comment: see if update works but I think something with apply will do better.

Comment: Man this is getting messy lol do you know of any other way? let me edit my question to give you a sense of what I am trying to do

Comment: I think it is harder to track when nested with `where` itself. See if update with apply works. You can change condition as you need and return value.

Comment: YES!!!!!!! Thank you, this is so much cleaner. You my friend are a god! +9000. Do you have any recommendations to get better at Python for data?